# Sort meteor collection based on array condition

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, sorting, meteor

Imagine that I need to sort the meteor mongo documents below based on "val" of the array "fields" that has "fieldName": "type".

```
    {
      "_id": "mCCPFQ5o9MP3rubze",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldName": "type",
          "val": "e-book",
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "title",
          "val": "4. Linux Bible"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "grMfahr2skiynkDuZ",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldName": "type",
          "val": "e-book",
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "title",
          "value": "5. Do the Tutorial"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "acbejXw98o8fSYqny",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldName": "type",
          "val": "e-book",
        },
        {
          "fieldName": "title",
          "val": "Putty"
        },
      ]
    }
```

How to do it in meteor using Mongo?

I fould lots of sort expressions and methods but nothing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `meteorhacks:aggregate` package to convert your array field to an object.

Here is the pipeline for MongoDB aggregation:

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 1, 
      'fields': 1, 
      'fieldsAsObjects': {
        '$arrayToObject': {
          '$map': {
            'input': '$fields', 
            'as': 'el', 
            'in': {
              'k': '$$el.fieldName', 
              'v': '$$el'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

after aggregation your documents should have `fieldsAsObjects` field:

```
[{
  "_id": "FrwqaRh8teWWLgXgy",
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "type",
      "val": "e-book"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "title",
      "val": "Putty"
    }
  ],
  "fieldsAsObjects": {
    "type": {
      "fieldName": "type",
      "val": "e-book"
    },
    "title": {
      "fieldName": "title",
      "val": "Putty"
    }
  }
},
{
  "_id": "CN57WS5EQGFBJPnck",
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "type",
      "val": "e-book"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "title",
      "value": "5. Do the Tutorial"
    }
  ],
  "fieldsAsObjects": {
    "type": {
      "fieldName": "type",
      "val": "e-book"
    },
    "title": {
      "fieldName": "title",
      "value": "5. Do the Tutorial"
    }
  }
}]
```

and you can sort them.